# How to align staggered rows into 1 column variable

Tags: python, merge

When merging similar csv files into a left dataset, a new column is created each time (running a loop through directory of csv files) rather than merging evverything into one column. The columns are identical in name except for _r to indicate the right dfs.

The code I used:

```
directory_path = 'black_male_65up_unemp'


left_dataset = dfpt2

#Loop through each file in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        # Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
        csv_path = os.path.join(directory_path, filename)
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
        dfpt2['state'] = dfpt2['state'].str.lower()
        df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].str.lower()
        df.drop(columns=['GEOID', 'variable', 'Unnamed: 0', 'moe'], inplace=True)
        # Merge
        left_dataset = pd.merge(left_dataset, df, how='left', left_on=['state', 'year'], right_on=      ['NAME', 'year'], suffixes=('','_r'))

#left_dataset.drop(columns=['merged_column'], inplace=True)
left_dataset
```

Here is the result of running this code. As you can see, its unaligned. The red lines are the the variable name which should be a single column. the black boxes show the rows that are unaligned.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
[Dataset output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM4NH.png)

I tried different types of merges; inner, outter... but failed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because exhibits are not in an accessible format.

Comment: How should I change the format?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you want is a single two-column output, you probably want to use `pd.concat([left_dataset, df], ignore_index=True)` instead of merge.